# Mixing general WPF styles with ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I came from web development and WinForms to WPF and maybe I didn't get the concept yet.
I'm able to define general styles for my Application in the app.xaml. For example I defined the style for all my ribbon controls in this file.

Then I tried Microsoft Blend and came across ResourceDictionary, which is somekind of Resource File .resx I knew from WinForms.

But as I see it's not possible to mix these two concepts. For example following xaml code will not work because ResourceDictionary have to be the only child.

```
<Application x:Class="Wpf.MyApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
             StartupUri="MyMainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/RibbonStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="IconDokumentNeu" >Images/NewDocument_32x32.png</BitmapImage>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGrayBrushKey">WhiteSmoke</SolidColorBrush>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="../time2_32.png" />
        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
    </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

It seems I didn't really get the concept. Maybe you can help me, why this is not possible and how I can use general styles next to ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You already have resources defined "next to" the dictionary, one image and one brush.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Dictionaries from file here -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- Other resources here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I know, but how I got it from MSDN descriptions, styles in a ResourceDictionary must have a key. But I want to define general styles without a key so they would be enabled as default.

Comment: @René: So the problem is that you get an error if you add a style with the same TargetType as a style in the merged dictionary?

Comment: Nope. I just didn't know that Resource Dictionary takes styles with just a TargetType without a key. Until now...

Answer (score 5):

Just include the {x:type} style in the resource dictionary

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
                   <!-- Dictionaries from file here -->  
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonWindow}">         
               <Setter Property="Icon" Value="../time2_32.png" />         
               <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />  
           </Style> 
     </ResourceDictionary>
```